# Get all child nodes of an Enterprise Architect package node

Tags: c#, console-application, com-interop, enterprise-architect

**What I need**

*Step 1*

I need to do an export of all information, whatever the node type, under a main root node (= package).

*Step 2*

Using that export information I need to do a mapping to a JSON contract provided by a third party.

*Step 3*

The third party can then use my JSON to import the information from EA into their system.

**What I have**

Step 1 is completed, I have a file based data dump on my target location like this:

[image]

Basically that's a static html website which corresponds to the EA structure by displaying the information in a tree-view, similar to how you see it in EA.

**What I can do**

Is go through the EARoot folder and read all information provided in the html files that are in there.

In my case EARoot contains three subfolders:

- EA1
- EA2
- EA3

Where the EA1 subfolders contains

- EA1
- EA2
- EA1.html
- EA2.html
- EA3.html

The html files contain the information I need, it's doable to interpret the data in a meaningful fashion.

**The catch**

Is that there's no immediate link to the files and the actual node structure in EA. I can make an assumption based on the available data, that will work -most- of the time, but it needs to be reliable and work -all- the time.

I can find a correct UUID in each html file, so that would be a way to link to the structure, but to find this structure, I need to be able to get the UUIDS of all children of a node and go through the tree recursively.

I tried the following:

```
public Package GetRootPackage()
{
    using (var repo = EnterpriseArchitect.Repository.Open(_connectionString))
    {
        return repo.GetPackage(this.RootPackageName);
    }
}
```

*EnterpriseArchitect.Repository is a wrapper on top of EA.Repository to have it be IDisposable for better connection management.*

Using the GetRootPackage method defined above, I can connect and load the node I want:

```
var root = MyBuilder.ConnectTo(myConnectionString)
    .RootPackage(rootNodeName)
    .GetRootPackage();
```

I'd think that I'd then be able to fetch it's children like so:

```
var children = root.Packages;
```

But then I get this nasty error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException   HResult=0x80010105
>   Message=The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))   Source=my.console
>   StackTrace:    at EA.IDualPackage.get_Elements()    at
>   my.console.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Repos\my.console\Program.cs:line 29

I checked eventviewer for more information and found (only) this:

```
Faulting application name: EA.exe, version: 14.1.0.1427, time stamp: 0x5b9718a5
Faulting module name: EA.exe, version: 14.1.0.1427, time stamp: 0x5b9718a5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0049ffc4
Faulting process id: 0x2eac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d56eb6d931a965
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\EA.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\EA.exe
Report Id: 223f8c89-c84a-45c6-9100-82af8e94643a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**The question**

What I find regarding this `HResult=0x80010105`seems to be Excel related, so I'm not sure if that's meaningful.

I'm running from a console, because I understood that `interop.EA` should be considered to be not-threadsafe.

> What can I do to avoid this issue and get the child packages?

Comment: RPC_E_SERVERFAULT is a COM/RPC error between the client (your code) and the server (EA). It seems related to Excel because Excel is just one of the most out-of-process COM server in the world :-). From the error in the Event Viewer, it seems to be a bug in EA.exe (maybe caused by something you do it doesn't like). You should contact the vendor.

Comment: @SimonMourier: I've contacted support, we'll see what the response is.

Comment: It would be most helpful to know what _C:\Repos\my.console\Program.cs:line 29_ looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `IDisposable` wrapper on top of `EA.Repository` that's causing the issue. If I call the repo directly (using `try catch finally` instead of `IDisposable`) I am able to get the child nodes.

So much for defensive programming ...

---

Instead of the wrapper I had:

```
public class Repository : IDisposable
{
    private EA.Repository _repo;

    protected Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        _repo = new EA.Repository();
        _repo.OpenFile(connectionString);
    }

    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _repo.CloseFile();
        _repo = null;
    }
}
```

I'm now using the EA repo directly to get (root) package information:

```
public Package GetRootPackage()
{
    var repo = new EA.Repository();

    try
    {    
        repo.OpenFile(_connectionString);

        var pkg = (EA.Package)repo.Models.GetByName(this.RootPackageName);

        if (pkg is null)
            throw new ApplicationException($"Package \"{this.RootPackageName}\" not found.");

        return pkg;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Closing repository...");
        repo.CloseFile();
    }
}
```

Through this I can do:

```
var root = MyBuilder.ConnectTo(myConnectionString)
    .RootPackage(rootNodeName)
    .GetRootPackage();

foreach (var item in root.Packages)
{
    var child = (IDualPackage)item;    
    var guid = child.PackageGUID;
}
```

And the `guid` var contains the correct `PackageGUID`.